# Canonical landscape custom graph script needs interpeter

Tags: openstack, landscape, monitoring

Okay so i am completely new to `Landscape` but i am starting to love it!

I want to create a graph that runs the following command:

```
netstat -an | grep -c 8105
```

Which will return a number of how many is connected to my servers socket!

So i pressed new graph:

[image]

Sadly as you can see from the picture i get the `script needs interpeter`

I am not sure what that means or how i get it to execute my command.

So i was hoping someone here could help me out and have tried it before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's asking you for a `#!/bin/bash` to tell it to run a bash script.

In the terminal, you are already running bash. When you run a command in a terminal it runs a bash command. To run bash commands as a script, you usually include a header that specifies the interpreter.

Use this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
netstat -an | grep -c 8105
```

If that doesn't work, use this instead:

```
/bin/bash -c netstat -an | grep -c 8105
```

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)